# How to prevent users from deactivating an android app admin permissions

Tags: android, admin, parental-control

Recently I've been doing some work on android apps and I am trying to make a 'Parental Control' type of app but I've ran into a major problem: I don't know how to prevent people from Uninstalling / Deactivating the app's admin status.
I have seen some other apps do that so I know it's possible.
Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't.  A factory reset will always wipe you out.  Now you may be looking for a lesser level of protection than that, in which case you need to define what it is a bit more.  Are you the legal owner of the device so you can do an ANdroid Enterprise rollout an manage the device?  Or are you actually planning to be a normal play store app?

Comment: 1. I don't intend to protect the app from a factory reset.
2. Let's just say for this matter that I am not going to publish it.

Comment: The Android Enterprise is probably your answer.  Ignore the fact it talks about business-  it allows remote administration and control over a device.  https://www.android.com/enterprise/